# Why syslog.1 growing?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I see that only syslog.1 is growing in size (Gbs). and rest of the logrotation process is working as usual. I do see compressed syslog2.gz, syslog.3.gz, etc.

Why only SYSLOG.1 is growing? Please help

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Open the log and read it. It's probably saying the same thing over and over again.

Comment: What probably he means is that syslog.1 is written to and it should be syslog. The .1 is the last backup. Probably a wrong log rotation. I see it a lot when using apache  so maybe that is the case here. syslog.1 never gets compressed where syslog would be if it was not empty :)

Comment: Yes @Rinzwind I'm curious about syslog.1.  If I'm required to free up space used by syslog.1, is it only by deleting/nullifying syslog.1?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the file `/var/log/syslog.1`?  The `lsof` command will tell you what process has the file open.

```
sudo lsof /var/log/syslog.1
```

I would only expect to see `rsyslogd` with any of the `/var/log/syslog*` files open.

Is this an program specific log, or have you customized a program to write to this file?  Some programs require a signal to tell them to start using a new log file after logrotate has run.  This is why many logrotate configs use a `postrotate` setting.  If the program does not have this feature then logrotate can be configured with `copytruncate`.  From the manpage http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/logrotate.8.html

> copytruncate
>
> Truncate the original log file to zero size in place after creating a copy, instead
> of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new one.  It can be used  when
> some  program  cannot  be told to close its logfile and thus might continue writing
> (appending) to the previous log file forever.  Note that there is a very small time
> slice  between  copying  the  file and truncating it, so some logging data might be
> lost.  When this option is used, the create option will have no effect, as the  old
> log file stays in place.